# How to show particular/specific legend on Google Chart

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

I want to show only specific legend and not all of it. I just need to choose 5 data and show it only on the legend part. Im using google pie chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `series` option, you can use property `visibleInLegend` (default = `true`)

to hide the first series from the legend...

```
series: {
  0: {
    visibleInLegend: false
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0', 'y1', 'y2'],
    [1, 5, 2, 6],
    [2, 6, 3, 7],
    [3, 7, 4, 8],
    [4, 8, 5, 9]
  ]);

  var options = {
    series: {
      0: {
        visibleInLegend: false
      }
    }
  };

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

for Pie charts, there is only one series allowed.
to manipulate the legend entries,
we must use the `slices` option, rather than `series`.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y'],
    ['A', 5],
    ['B', 6],
    ['C', 7],
    ['D', 8]
  ]);

  var options = {
    slices: {
      0: {
        visibleInLegend: false
      }
    }
  };

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I see that it works but when i try it on pie chart. it wont work

Comment: what if i want to show 5 specific legend only? Thank you ♥

Comment: you would coordinate the slice number with the row number in the data table of the label you want to show...